# C OpenGL glfw3 triangle not displaying

Tags: c, opengl, graphics, glfw

I have a simple OpenGL C application that attempts to draw a triangle on screen. I have successfully written similar code in C++ with no problems. When I run the C program it creates the window, but nothing is displayed. The main chunk of my code is below.

```
void init()
{   
GLfloat vertices[] = {
    // Positions         
    0.0f,  0.5f, 0.0f, 0.0f,    // Top
    0.5f, -0.5f, 0.0f, 0.0f,    // Bottom Right
    -0.5f, -0.5f, 0.0f, 0.0f    // Bottom Left 
};

    GLuint vao;
    glGenVertexArrays(1, &vao);
    glBindVertexArray(vao);

    GLuint buffer;
    glGenBuffers(1, &buffer);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, buffer);
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(vertices), vertices, GL_STATIC_DRAW);
    //glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);

    GLuint program = loadShader("/shader1.vert", 
        "/shader1.frag");
    glUseProgram(program);

    GLuint vPosition = glGetAttribLocation(program, "VPosition");
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(vPosition);
    glVertexAttribPointer(vPosition, 4, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, BUFFER_OFFSET(0));
    glBindVertexArray (vao);
}

int main()
{
    glfwInit();
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_RESIZABLE, GL_FALSE);
    int w = 800;
    int h = 600;

    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_RESIZABLE, GL_FALSE);
    //glfwSetInputMode(window, GLFW_STICKY_KEYS, GL_TRUE);
    GLFWwindow* window = glfwCreateWindow(WIDTH, HEIGHT, "glfw3", NULL, NULL);
    glfwMakeContextCurrent(window);
    glfwSetKeyCallback(window, key_callback);
    glViewport(0, 0, WIDTH, HEIGHT);

    init();

    while(!glfwWindowShouldClose(window))
    {
        glfwPollEvents();
        glClearColor(0.2f, 0.3f, 0.3f, 1.0f);
        glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
        glDrawArrays( GL_TRIANGLES, 0, 3 );
        glfwSwapBuffers(window);
    }

    glfwTerminate();
    return 0;
}
```

With the vertex shader

```
attribute vec4 vPosition;
void main()
{
    gl_Position = vPosition;
}
```

and the fragment shader

```
void main()
{
    gl_FragColor = vec4( 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0 );
}
```

And loading the shaders

```
char *readShader(char *filename)
{
FILE *fp;
char *content = NULL;

int count = 0;
if(filename != NULL)
{
    fp = fopen(filename, "rt");
    if(fp != NULL){
        fseek(fp, 0, SEEK_END);
        count = ftell(fp);
        rewind(fp);
        if (count > 0) {
            content = (char *)malloc(sizeof(char) * (count+1));
            count = fread(content,sizeof(char),count,fp);
            content[count] = '\0';
        }
    }
    fclose(fp);
}
return content; 
}

GLuint loadShader(char *vertex_path, char *fragement_path)
{   
GLuint vertShader = glCreateShader(GL_VERTEX_SHADER);
GLuint fragShader = glCreateShader(GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER);

char *vertShaderStr = readShader(vertex_path);
char *fragShaderStr = readShader(fragement_path);

printf("Compiling vertex shader\n");
GLint vertLength = strlen(vertShaderStr);
glShaderSource(vertShader, 1, (const char **)&vertShaderStr, &vertLength);
glCompileShader(vertShader);

//Check vertex shader
GLint vertSuccess;
glGetShaderiv(vertShader, GL_COMPILE_STATUS, &vertSuccess);
if(vertSuccess == GL_FALSE) {
    char log[1024];
    glGetShaderInfoLog(vertShader, sizeof(log), 0, log);
    printf("Vertex shader compile info: \n %s \n", log);
    glDeleteShader(vertShader);
    return 1;
}


printf("Compiling fragment shader\n");
GLint fragLength = strlen(fragShaderStr);
glShaderSource(fragShader, 1, (const char **)&fragShaderStr, &fragLength);
glCompileShader(fragShader);

//Check fragment shader
GLint fragSuccess;
glGetShaderiv(fragShader, GL_COMPILE_STATUS, &fragSuccess);
if(vertSuccess == GL_FALSE) {
    char log[1024];
    glGetShaderInfoLog(vertShader, sizeof(log), 0, log);
    printf("Fragment shader compile info: \n %s \n", log);
    glDeleteShader(fragShader);
    return 1;
}

printf("Linking program\n");
GLuint program = glCreateProgram();
glAttachShader(program, vertShader);
glAttachShader(program, fragShader);
glLinkProgram(program);

GLint programSuccess;
glGetProgramiv(program, GL_LINK_STATUS, &programSuccess);
if(programSuccess == GL_FALSE) {
    char log[1024];
    glGetProgramInfoLog(program, sizeof(log), 0, log);
    printf("shader link info: \n %s \n", log);
    glDeleteProgram(program);
    return 1;
}

//printf("%s", vertShaderStr);
//printf("%s", fragShaderStr);
return program;
}
```

Comment: I am a beginner in OpenGL myself but from what I can see you never unbind your vao

Comment: Where are your `#version` directives?  `loadShader()` implementation?

Comment: All 3 of your vertices are on a line. So no matter what you do for rendering (I did not look at the rest of the code), you would not cover any pixels.

Comment: Fixed triangles vertices (I had tried several different vertices before) unfortunately still the same thing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here:
    GLfloat vertices[] = {
        // Positions
        0.0f,  0.5f, 0.0f, 0.0f,    // Top
        0.5f, -0.5f, 0.0f, 0.0f,    // Bottom Right
        -0.5f, -0.5f, 0.0f, 0.0f    // Bottom Left 
    }

you are specifying 0 as w coordinate for all of your vertices. You really want to put 1 here, otherwise your vertices are indefinitely far away.

Note that usually the input w`coordinates of all your vertices is always 1 and it is a waste of memory and bandwith to explicitely store this in the array. The GL will automatically extend the fourth component of vectors to 1 if it is not specified, so you could simply use

```
GLfloat vertices[] = {
    // Positions         
    0.0f,  0.5f, 0.0f,    // Top
    0.5f, -0.5f, 0.0f,    // Bottom Right
    -0.5f, -0.5f, 0.0f,   // Bottom Left 
};
// ...
glVertexAttribPointer(vPosition, 3 GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, BUFFER_OFFSET(0));
```

*without* changing your `attribute vec4` in the shader at all.

What I also find suspicious is that you never load the GL function pointers. I have not pasted what headers you include, but the could will definitely not work on all platforms.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Than was one of the problems in my code it is working now.